# WearableListenerSerivce onMessageReceived not called with same applicationID

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-service, watch

I'm developing an Android Application with a Watch module (applicationID is the same for the app and watch). I'm testing the communication with a real device and a watch emulator, but since last day no message arrive in WearableListenerService and I don't understand why.

This is my Service (app device) in manifest

```
<service
        android:name=".receivers.PhoneMessageService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="wear" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

The app Listener

```
class PhoneMessageService : WearableListenerService() {

override fun onMessageReceived(message: MessageEvent?)
{
    message?.let { msg ->
        sendActionToReceiver(msg.path, msg)
    }
}
```

With this method I get the nodes (i always getthe node of my phone, infact nodes is always size 1):

```
 private fun getNodes(context: Context, mode: WearCommunicationMode, callback: ((Node?) -> Unit))
{
    val capability = Wearable.getCapabilityClient(context).getCapability(mode.capabilityKey, CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE)
    capability.addOnSuccessListener { task ->
        val nodes = task?.nodes
        if(nodes != null && nodes.size > 0) {
            val bestNodeID = nodes.find { node -> node.isNearby } ?: nodes.first()
            callback.invoke(bestNodeID)
        }else{
            callback.invoke(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Nodes size is 1, so I'm connected with device, but onMessageReceived isnt't called anymore... what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<service
    android:name=".receivers.PhoneMessageService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:scheme="wear" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**exported needs to be true!**